# Unit test for jms integration development

Tags: java, unit-testing, jms, integration

Recently i working for jms integration. The message provider side is also developing in parallel. What's on my hand is just a .xsd schema and sample message.

Since there will be lots of scenario i have to check. Like data record already existing in db, bad/broke message etc.

How to do the integration test/unit test locally ?

thanks in advanced!

Comment: So what are you asking a question about? Integration testing or unit testing? Two completely different things with completely different methods of approach.

Comment: The question indicates to me that OP does not really know the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry for the my bad description. I should say like this: 
Currently i can't do the "real" integration test because the message provider side is not ready. Like @Adriaan Koster mentioned. So i have to create a mock sender to send the mock message to the queue/topic. Then consume it to check if it's expected message format. Since it's all mock stuff in local and i consider it's kind of unit test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a world of difference between integration tests and unit tests.

My interpretation of unit tests are white-box tests for a single class (unit) which focus on testing the internal logic. This is commonly done with JUnit. I use mocking (Mockito, Powermock) to isolate the class from any dependencies it has on other classes or its environment (file system, network, CPU threads, time, etc). In your case you should have separate components that handle network, (un)marshalling, business logic, and storage. Writing unit tests for the component that contains the business logic would be the easiest en most useful in my opinion. The others would be more framework/vendor specific and usually harder to unit test; they will be covered by integration tests.

Integration tests cover the end-to-end flow through your application. To create them you need to set up all application components, environment and remote systems realistically. For example you could create a test message provider which sends a JMS message to your application, you could run an embedded webserver (e.g. Jetty) to host your application and you could run an in-memory database as test storage. A good framework I've used for this is [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) but there are certainly many other good solutions.

EDIT: After reading your comment.

Unit testing does not involve any interaction with the environment (network, file system etc), not even when you use your own stub components to send real messages to you over the local network. That is integration testing.

Once you test using the message provider created and managed by another team you are out of the realm of automated testing. This is because you cannot guarantee that this external message provider will be available always and everywhere. Automated tests should be runnable independently on your own machines with at most a single click.